# Why wkhtmltopdf produces a blank PDF on Bookdown's web pages?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I can't figure out why this command produces an empty PDF:

```
wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 3000 https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html result.pdf
```

[This website](https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html) (produced by Bookdown) doesn't interest me especially, I'm just trying to understand the limits of wkhtmltopdf. Thank you in advance for your help/information.

Comment: use http instead of https

Comment: @NarenderGodara Already tried, but same result

Comment: is this working with different url??

Comment: Of course. `wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 3000 http://www.google.com result.pdf` works.

Comment: For me - it was a page behind a login - my pdf generator code was making a request to the website but as I don't have the user session in this request it was redirecting to a login page - and producing a blank pdf.